# How to get only the OutputKey from boto3 cloudformation describe_stack API?

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, boto3

Need some help! I'm trying to deploy CloudFormation stack using boto3. In the cloudformation template, have the below code for Outputs parameter. When I run describe_stack, it shows me the complete description of the stack and all the properties. How do I fetch only some of them from the below OutputKeys? For example, what if I want only the PublicDNS or PublicIP?

```
Outputs:
  InstanceId:
    Description: InstanceId of the newly created EC2 instance
    Value: !Ref EC2Instance
  AZ:
    Description: Availability Zone of the newly created EC2 instance
    Value: !GetAtt 
      - EC2Instance
      - AvailabilityZone
  PublicDNS:
    Description: Public DNSName of the newly created EC2 instance
    Value: !GetAtt 
      - EC2Instance
      - PublicDnsName
  PublicIP:
    Description: Public IP address of the newly created EC2 instance
    Value: !GetAtt 
      - EC2Instance
      - PublicIp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do as follows (example for `PublicDNS`) with the help of [Stack](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Stack):

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id='', aws_secret_access_key=''...) 

cloudformation = session.resource('cloudformation')

stack = cloudformation.Stack('<your-stack-name>')

print(stack.outputs)

public_dns = ''

for output in stack.outputs:
    if output['OutputKey'] == 'PublicDNS':
        public_dns = output['OutputValue']
        break

print(public_dns)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I already have a boto3 session and a client created to CloudFormation. How can I use the same session and client for the above Output operation?

`session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id='', aws_secret_access_key=''...)
cf_client = session.client('cloudformation')`

Comment: @SupreetKulkarni Sorry, I don't understand the question. Just use your session to call `session.resource('cloudformation')`.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase it. In the same python code, I already have defined a session and client to connect to cloudformation as mentioned above. With that, if I use `cloudformation = boto3.resource('cloudformation')`, I will need to again pass the session credentials. Wondering how can I avoid that.

Comment: @SupreetKulkarni I updated the answer. Please have a look now.